# How to create some pages with blur text like in sample image

Tags: transparency, watermark

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % Package to generate dummy text throughout this template
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{times}[3.35139mm] % Use the Palatino font
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\linespread{1.15} % Line spacing - Palatino needs more space between line
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics
%\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyperref, graphicx}
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,margin=16.51mm, top=20mm, bottom=25mm,columnsep=20pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{flafter}
```